# remove NULLS rows in a Dynamic SQL Pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Good Day. Please help me remove NULLS rows in a Dynamic SQL Pivot:

[image]

The query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  person_id,
    Name,
    activity_id,
    concat(activity collate database_default, 
           case when activity = 'maintainance' 
                then row_number() over (partition by Name,activity order by activitydate) 
                else '' 
           end  collate database_default) as activity
FROM PesonActivities    
)t
PIVOT(MAX(activity_id) FOR activity IN (
[purchased],
[installed],
[maintainance1],
[maintainance2],
[maintainance3]))p
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: where is the `Dynamic SQL Pivot` query ?

Answer (score 1):

I would just add a WHERE after the PIVOT

```
...
Where concat([purchased],[installed],[maintainance1],[maintainance2],[maintainance3])<>''
```